# How to fix constraints for 4 horizontal label?

Tags: swift, xcode

I made a view for shop schedule. One line for each day so I have 7 lines with 4 labels. I used constraints with same value for each space between label and same value for each label. For iphone SE / 5S, it's OK. But for bigger devices, one of the label is bigger to adjust view.

I tried to play with the constraints values or with the relation (Equal / Greater than) but nothing change. What I have to do to keep same values for label and same values for space ?
Thanks

iPhone screen:

[image: iphone screen]

Xcode constraints:

[image: XCode]

Comment: Please add some code or screenshots.

Comment: Use CollectionView

Comment: use 'UIStackView'

Comment: Use Horizontal Stackview with Fill Equally Distribution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

---

Your layout looks like it could benefit from being in a tableView, but let's look at just your horizontal constraints.

This is a great place to use a *Stack View*.  Do the following:

1. Get rid of all horizontal constraints for the 4 labels.
2. Select the 4 labels (by holding <kbd>shift</kbd> and clicking on each label) and then choose **Editor -> Embed In -> Stack View** from the Xcode menu.
3. In the *Attributes Inspector* on the right, make sure Stack View *Axis* is **Horizontal**.
4. Set *Alignment* to **Fill**, *Distribution* to **Fill Equally**, *Spacing* to **`16`**.
5. Give your Stack View leading and trailing constraints to Safe Area leading and trailing.

and you're done.  Your labels will grow equally to fill in the space for each phone.

---

[image: Setup in Xcode]

---

**Next steps:**

You can compose Stack Views (put Stack Views inside other Stack Views).

For your setup:

1. Add a label above the 4 labels for the day of the week (eg. Lundi).
2. Select this new label and the 4-labels Stack View and embed those into a **Vertical** Stack View, *Alignment*: **Fill**, *Distribution*: **Fill Equally**, *Spacing*: **`16`**.
3. Make six more copies of this new Stack View for the other days of the week, and embed those in a **Vertical** Stack View, *Alignment*: **Fill**, *Distribution*: **Equal Spacing**.
4. For this outermost Stack View, give it constraints to place it on the screen.  If you constrain its top, bottom, leading, and trailing edges to the Safe Area, the Stack View will fill the phone's screen, and the days of the week will be spaced out to fill it nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Just do the following:

1. Remove the trailing constraint for each "1:00" label.
2. Add the equal-width constraint for each label in the same row.

Comment: In particular, you will need 3 equal-width constraints for each row: lab1.width == lab2.width, lab1.width == lab3.width, lab1.width == lab4.width, or you could chain them 1==2, 2==3, 3==4.

Comment: In addition to the 3 equal width constraints, you'll want lab.1.leading == safe.leading, lab4.trailing == safe.trailing, lab2.leading = lab1.trailing + 16, lab3.leading = lab2.trailing + 16, lab4.leading = lab3.trailing + 16.  This will establish the boundaries and spaces, and the labels will grow equally to fill in the space.